# Docker command failed with exit code 0: "/nuget.config" not found

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dockerfile

I had a Dockerfile set up to for a Visual Studio ASP.NET Core project running on Windows. Every time I tried to debug in Docker, I got the following error:

`Docker command failed with exit code 0`

The build output showed:

`error CTC1014: failed to compute cache key: "/nuget.config" not found: not found`

Comment: Do you resolved this?

Comment: @MarcosReis Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the NuGet config file in source control was `NuGet.Config`. It should have been lowercase: `nuget.config`.